# Unable to login with a domain account

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a virtual server running Windows Server 2008 R2 joined to a domain.  The guy who cloned the this server from another server of ours on the domain, didn't `sysprep` the clone before it was renamed and joined to the domain.

So I ran `sysprep` then rejoined the domain, but now I can't login to it with any domain accounts.  It recognizes that it's a part of the domain, but only the local administrator can log in.  I had a local account before sysprep, and it remained afterward.  I deleted it, tried again, but still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems logging in to AD typically revolve around either DNS problems or Time Synchronization problems.  Verify that the VM's time is within 5 min of your domain controllers' times.  And verify that the VM is pointing to the proper DNS servers.

You should also be able to get some clues as to what is going on from the Event Logs on the VM when logging in as your local account.

Comment: Ah hah!  We may have a winner.  DNS appears to be fine, but the clock is off by just less than 5 minutes.

Comment: Now I just need to figure out how to update the time... `net time \\dc /set /y` fails with 'service not started', but Windows Time *is* started... :/

Comment: I was able to update the time by running `net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /rediscover` as a local admin and `net time \\dc /set /y` as a domain admin, but still no joy for logging in.

Comment: I'm getting `Domain sid inconsistent` in the event log, but I ran `sysprep`...

Comment: Were your domain controllers also built from non-sysprep'd images?

Comment: I hope not...  o_0

Comment: I have 3 other virtual machines on the domain that don't have problems though.

Comment: When you ran sysprep on the VM, did you check the box for "Generalize"?

Comment: *gives deer in headlights look* :][